# Extract one object from set of objects

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, edge-detection

I want to extract one leaf from bunch of leaves to detect its features using OpenCV (C++). So first I tried to find edges of the image and extract one object. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435268/extract-one-object-from-bunch-of-objects-and-detect-edges)., but it seems that this way is not going to work. What I want to do is just extract one leaf from an image taken in real environment of the plant (See the following example image this is only an example. The image that is going to process is not known previously user has to take an image and to upload to the system)

[image]

As an example consider I want to cut off the leaf marked with red line.
Then I can proceed to identify features of that leaf. Can any one please suggest a step by step method to do this. I'm using OpenCV and C++ as the language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSLDCKeM5YE maybe the code posted code be of some assitance

Comment: Take a look at GrabCut in OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html, http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#grabcut

Comment: Have a look at ch5 of http://szeliski.org/Book/. Given there are many leaves in that image, how do you know which one? Does the method have to be completely automatic, or can it be guided by a user? Your problem is  actually quite difficult, and the question is too broad (but it is an interesting problem). Are you only looking for leaves of this type of plant, or might it be a cactus leaf, or a frangipani leaf?

Comment: maybe it's always the biggest object/contour in the image? Once you've found the object, you can separate it by creating a mask only holding the region of that object (e.g. fillContour) and use `originalImage.copyTo(objectImage, mask)`

Comment: @Micka Yes we can consider it as the largest object always, but how to create the mask because in all the cases this is not the image the image will change based on the plant. Can you please explain more. Thank you for the comment.