# Detect multiple 3d shapes in an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently learning OpenCV for a project I recently started in, and need to detect 3D boxes (imagine the big plastic boxes maybe 3ft x 2ft x 2ft) in an image. I've used the inRange method to create an image which just had the boxes I'd like to detect in it, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I'd like to get a 3D representation of these boxes back from OpenCV, but I can't figure out how. I've found quite a few tutorials explaining how to do this with just one object (which I have done successfully), but I don't know how I would make this work with multiple boxes in one image.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post the critical snippet of the code you have yet along with a [minimal main() program that runs that snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. For the convenience of answerers, best add the line from your build log that contains the compiler invocation.

Comment: are the boxes standing on the same planar ground?

Answer (score 0):

If you have established a method that works well with one object, you may just go with a divide-and-conquer approach: split your problem into several small ones by dividing your image with multiple boxes into an several images with one object.

1. Apply an Object Detector to your image. [This Tutorial on Object Detection may help you](https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/). A quick search for object detection with OpenCV also gave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435268/extract-one-object-from-bunch-of-objects-and-detect-edges).
2. Determine the bounding boxes of the objects (min/max of the x and y-coordinates, maybe add some border margin)
3. Crop bounding boxes to get single object images
4. Apply your already working method to the set of single object images

In case of overlap, the cropped images may need some processing to isolate a "main" object. Whether 4. works is then dependent on how robust your method is to occlusions.

---

*I stumbled over your question when looking for object detection. It's been quite a while since you asked, but since this is a public knowledge base a discussion on this topic might still be helpful for others.*